# How to deserialize a complex IRestresponse into a List of C# objects

Tags: c#, json, list, serialization

I am using IRestresponse to fetch the json content from the server. It is a complex json and I want to deserialize it into a list of object that imitates the json hirerachy(Basically a DTO class) and fetch it while iterating it through the list. 
I have done it through RestAssured through java.....but cannot find the solution in C#

```
        #the following code is in java. This class imitates the Json Object and follows it's hierarchy
        public class MyPojo
        {


            private String code;

            private String lastActive;

            private PrimaryContactExpanded primaryContactExpanded;

            private PrimaryContact primaryContact;

            private String id;

            private Status status;

            public String getCode ()
            {
                return code;
            }

            public void setCode (String code)
            {
                this.code = code;
            }

            public String getLastActive ()
            {
                return lastActive;
            }

            public void setLastActive (String lastActive)
            {
                this.lastActive = lastActive;
            }

            public PrimaryContactExpanded getPrimaryContactExpanded ()
            {
                return primaryContactExpanded;
            }

            public void setPrimaryContactExpanded (PrimaryContactExpanded primaryContactExpanded)
            {
                this.primaryContactExpanded = primaryContactExpanded;
            }

            public PrimaryContact getPrimaryContact ()
            {
                return primaryContact;
            }

            public void setPrimaryContact (PrimaryContact primaryContact)
            {
                this.primaryContact = primaryContact;
            }

            public String getId ()
            {
                return id;
            }

            public void setId (String id)
            {
                this.id = id;
            }

            public Status getStatus ()
            {
                return status;
            }

            public void setStatus (Status status)
            {
                this.status = status;
            }


        //In order to deserialize it and fetch it through a list I have used the following code


    List<MyPojo> customers = response.jsonPath().getList(".", MyPojo.class);

                //System.out.println(response.jsonPath().get("primaryContactExpanded.companyName"));
                for(MyPojo customer : customers)
         {
                    System.out.println(customer.getId());
                    System.out.println(customer.getPrimaryContactExpanded().getDisplayAs());
                }

It performs the deserialization of an json object into a list of MyPojo class
And I can fetch the values while iterating it through the list 
        How can I perform the same for IRestSharp response and deserialize it into a list of List of a class object and for each iteration fetch the values

    I am not able to perform the same task in C#.
```

Comment: since json is a string, use Newtonsoft to deserialize to class
```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CLASSNAME>(getresultStr);
```
and class will contain propery as List<detailsobject>()

Comment: Hi @PowerMouse I am not able to understand the part "List<detailsobject>" that you have specified......could you be a more elaborate

Comment: Are you trying to say something like this??  var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CLASSNAME>>(jsonstring);